# How can I update excel data using nodejs express

Tags: node.js, excel, express

I have an excel sheet there are two columns one is the product name and the other is the product price and the price column is empty, to get the price I have to call API and then update the excel sheet with that price How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) to work with excels. You can do something like this:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

workbook.xlsx.readFile('path to file')
    .then(() => {
        const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        const row = worksheet.getRow(15);
        row.getCell(1).value = 'pass_new_value';
        row.commit();
        return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('path-to-new-file');
    }).catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
    })
```

I would suggest you get all the data first and then write to the sheet instead of updating one column at a time.